# Show Posts By Custom Field

Tags: posts, customization, loop

I’d like to add 2 custom fields to my posts:

1. `show_post_on_home_page`
2. `home_page_posts_order_sequence`

I then want my home page to show only the posts where `show_on_home_page == true`, ordered by `home_page_posts_order_sequence`.

Does anyone have a template file or sample code that I can use to achieve this?

I also have not found a theme, plugin, or article that provides this type of functionality when I would expect the need to be great.

I have seen some samples using the Menu Order but they were not clean or elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, this question shouldn't exist, it has been answered hundreds of times across the web..

Im going to answer *the most tricky* part - query itself. Everything else is simple `HTML` and `PHP`. You can also find examples in link I provided below. If you can't do `PHP` and `HTML` yourself, you shouldn't ask this question and should be learning `PHP` and `HTML` *(which is rather easy to pick up)*.

```
$args = array(

    'post_type'         => 'your-post-type-name',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1, //-1 means "get all posts", 5 would mean "get 5 posts" etc

    'meta_query'        => array(
        array(
            'key'           => 'show_on_home_page',
            'value'         => true,
            'compare'       => 'IN', //Possible values: '=' '>' '<' etc
        )
    ),
    //In order to order by custom meta, you will need to make sure it exists
    'meta_query'        => array(
        array(
            'key'           => 'home_page_posts_order_sequence',
            'compare'       => 'exists',
            //Specifying type is VERY recommended, otherwise it might go wrong
            'type'          => 'numeric',
        )
    ),

    'orderby'           => array( 'home_page_posts_order_sequence' => 'DESC' );
    // DESC: descending order         ASC: ascending order
);

$query_results = new WP_Query( $args );
```

**Read more from [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)**.

Comment: Why are you using a `LIKE` comparison to check for true. `LIKE` comparisons are far more expensive that the default `IN` comparator.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Thanks for pointing that out. It's nice to learn new things every day. :)